# select same column from multiple rows based on other values

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am working on a query that draws data from several tables under certain conditions. The columns in the result set have to include values for 1-3 types of addresses. This is a typical 1 Patron to 1,3 Patron Address relation.

There are three address blocks needed in my result set. (This is for a system conversion from on ILS  to another in our academic library.)

Everyone, from what I can tell, has a row in the `PATRON_ADDRESS` table for `ADDRESS_TYPE='1'`, which is a street address

Some also have a `Address_Type = '2'`, which is sometimes just a `campusmailbox` number and sometimes a real address

Most have an `Address_Type = '3'`, which is email address.
Yes I agree.  That is a poor database design in the source system.

I have a data structure like this that I need to populate:

```
PATRON name, primary address street city state zip (Address_type 1), secondary address street city state zip (Address_Type 2) and an email field.
```

Note that, while the underlying database is Oracle, in my current role I am only able to access the data through MS Access 2007 (bleah!). So things I might know I can do in Oracle I assume won't work in Access SQL.

So I need to pull rows from the same table, `PATRON_ADDRESS`, based on the `patron_id` field. Is this query below

For every `patron_ID` and `address_type` in the `Patron` Table, I need to conditionally select column values from the `Patron_Address` table. Is this query going to do what I need?

```
Select P.PATRON.P.PATRON_ID,P.PATRON.LAST_NAME, 

A1.StrretAddress_line1,A1.StreetAddress_Line2,etc.,A2.StreetAddress_Line1, A2.StreetAddress_Line2, A3.StreetAddress_Line1

from PATRON P, PATRON_ADDRESS A1, PATRON_ADDRESS A2, PATRON_ADDRESS A3

where (P.PATRON_ID = A1.PATRON_ID and
       A1.ADDRESS_TYPE = '1')
and
     (P.PATRON_ID = A2.PATRON_ID and
       A2.ADDRESS_TYPE = '2')
and
    (P.PATRON_ID = A3.PATRON_ID and
       A3.ADDRESS_TYPE = '3');
```

I realize that this will be rather inefficient, but I don't know how I would reference the individual columns if I did an inner JOIN of `PATRON_ADDRESS` for the `address type = 1` data, and two outer joins of `PATRON_ADDRESS` to get the `address type = 2` and `address_type = 3` data respectively. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your data structure. "PATRON name, primary address street city state zip (Address_type 1), secondary address street city state zip (Address_Type 2) and an email field." Is that 4 fields, then?  Furthermore, can you show a couple lines of example data and your desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just `JOIN` the table in for each address. It's very similar to what you have, but you **really** should be using `JOIN` syntax, not listing all of your tables in the `FROM` clause. That form of joining tables isn't clear, can't accomplish what the `JOIN` clause can, and has been falling (has fallen) out of use for 20 years.

```
SELECT
    P.patron_id,
    P.last_name,
    PA1.streetaddress_line1,
    ...
    PA2.streetaddress_line2,
    ...
    PA3.streetaddress_line3
FROM
    Patron P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Patron_Address PA1 ON
    PA1.patron_id = P.patron_id AND
    PA1.address_type = '1'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Patron_Address PA2 ON
    PA2.patron_id = P.patron_id AND
    PA2.address_type = '2'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Patron_Address PA3 ON
    PA3.patron_id = P.patron_id AND
    PA3.address_type = '3'
```

If you know that everyone has an address of type 1 then you could make that an `INNER JOIN`.